# Reposting subjective questions as community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, subjective, duplicate-questions

After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443787/if-you-werent-a-programmer-what-would-you-be-doing-closed) was closed [Bill K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12943/bill-k) suggested reposting the question as community wiki, as there seemed to be a lot of people interested in the topic.

If a subjective question is closed and the OP does not show interest in editing to make the question more "acceptable", is it OK to repost as community wiki?

Comment: Keep in mind, CW doesn't automatically turn a trollish ("vi vs. emacs: fight!") or pointless ("i'm bored, tell me a story") post into a worthy one. Put some effort into cleaning it up, and use your judgment in deciding whether it's worth the trouble; worst case, it'll get closed as a dup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443787/if-you-werent-a-programmer-what-would-you-be-doing) was [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444873/if-you-werent-a-programmer-what-would-you-be-doing) it devolved into a flame war, and has been closed and reopened repeatedly. Perhaps this is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

I'm torn.

On the one hand, Stack Overflow is meant to be a Programming Q & A site, and the further we go from that, the higher the signal-to-noise ratio gets.

On the other hand, I really enjoy some of the 'softer' posts, and I think they ought to be allowed because SO is a 'community'.  If we had a community tab that hid 'community discussion' questions, then absolutely.

Comment: ++. IMHO, a big part of the problem with using SO as a discussion forum is that, the questions get mixed in with each other, softer questions tend to encourage more soft questions, dups, near-dups, and non-CW knockoffs. It'd be nice if the SO team just tacked on an actual forum for these things.

Comment: And had a mechanism to automatically transfer a question that is asked in SO directly to a forum post.

Comment: Yes.  I'd like a 'community tab' where everything like this is hidden in by default, and doesn't' clog up the front page.  Part of the propagation of this is because people see it on the front page.

Comment: I wonder if the soft questions that are not marked Community Wiki are not intended to stir up conversation and generate up votes for the member asking the question.  It makes sense, since SO has been modeled as a game and some notable micro-celebrities claim to "play" StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fine to me.

As Shog9 points out, just making it a CW does not guarantee that it won't still be closed. I'm just saying that reworking and reposting a question isn't in and of itself an issue.

Answer (score 0):

That seems backward to me.  Posts that carry no possibility of negative consequences would tend to encourage worse behavior not better.  I guess people are tired of seeing others get lots of points for "soft" questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Gortok - a toggle to hide community discussions would clear the site up while still letting people enjoy the community aspects when they want to.  Nonetheless, I really wouldn't want to see *any* political or religious discussions or anything that goes too far afield from software development.

Has anyone suggested this in UserVoice?