# Subjective and Argumentative vs. Subjective or Argumentative?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, not-constructive

Ok I just saw a comment on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875533/what-features-do-you-want-to-see-in-net-5-c-5) and it got me to thinking (which is never good ;-) can I ask questions which **are** subjective **but not** argumentative without them being closed?

If I can't, shouldn't it be worded subjective **or** argumentative?

Comment in question:

`Subjective but not particularly argumentative. I like it. Re-open.` – [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293522/charles)

Comment: An area of active debate. You see, you haven't hit the fun part yet. Compare the close reason description to the FAQ: *"Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion."* Then stand back and watch the fur fly...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subjective: FAQ versus close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47749/subjective-faq-versus-close-reasons)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subjective question wars, iteration 3.14159](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50499/subjective-question-wars-iteration-3-14159)

Comment: @closevoters why is this closed, not just [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 2):

In the name of consolidation and simplifying the existing standard close reasons, we're changing this reason from "subjective and argumentative" to

> **not constructive**
>
> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of open subjective questions on SO - fewer now than in the past, but they're often accepted.  I personally think (not that I frankly care a whole lot about it) that the close reason could be changed to just "argumentative", as that's the core problem with most questions closed with that reason.

To answer your specific question: if you have a "subjective" question to ask, make it answerable and interesting, such that the answers will be useful for others. If I'm on the fence about closing a question, I'll read the answers so far, and gauge if the discussion is heading in a good or bad direction.